# Implementing a back button without navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, user-interface

I'm kind of new to programming in swift and in general in xcode. I'm creating my first app and i've run into this issue that i cant seem to find a fix for online..

my first scene is a view controller with two buttons where you pick a language and it redirects you to the appropriate tab controller in that language.. now I'd like to add a back button to those tab controllers in order to go back in case you picked the wrong language.
what I've tried so far doesn't really work..
I have tried using a navigation controller but they dont show on the first view controller so that doesnt help me, ive tried putting just a navigation bar and adding a navigation item (see pictures below) but the back button isnt rendered correctly and cannot be reached..

[image: my working scene]

[image: when i try using a navigation bar]

[image: what happens when i run my code..]

help is much appreciated !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use first UIView and set top constraint 0 with safe area. See image[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Please check this https://www.raywenderlich.com/443-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-11-getting-started

Comment: Also, how do I make the UIView match the background/fill in up to the top so i dont have an issue with the orange background?

Comment: You can give background color to UIView

Comment: @Nicole custom UIView will cause issue in iphone X and new iPhone series ,you can put navigation bar in your view controller and add button.Navigation bar will manage automatically everything on all device